API to create files(yml,js) for cubes and view
I am looking for cubejs API's around model files on /playground/files probably. Basically to create yml and js files in conf/model/ folders. Is it available?
I could get the existing model files by doing GET API on /playground/files which gives me a response like with filename, content and abspath.
"files": [
    {
        "fileName": "cubes/cube1.yml",
        "content": "cubes:\r\r\n - name: cube1\r\r\n ",
        "absPath": "/cube/conf/model/cubes/cube1.yml"
    }    ]

I am trying to do a PUT with content, filename and path which would create a file and make the measures and dim in playground.
